# Can you execute another build yml from inside a azure pipeline build yml?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We would like to make our azure pipeline build .ymls modular. For a full application build will include build .ymls for different components into a main .yml that will build them all together. For the components individually we will just call the single .yml to build that component. Can another build .yml be executed from within a build .yml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we can use ymls modularly with [template references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#template-references).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Here is an example of how to do this with a predefined node template mixed with an inline yarn installer:

```
- job: Build
  steps:
  - template: ../Tasks/node.yml

  - task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-installer-task.YarnInstaller@2
    displayName: 'use yarn 1.x'

    inputs:
      checkLatest: true

  - template: ../Tasks/yarn.yml
    parameters:
      projectDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
```

node.yml:

```
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 10.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 10.x
```

yarn.yml:

```
parameters:
- name: projectDirectory
  type: string
- name: arguments
  type: string
  default: 'install'

steps:
  - task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-task.Yarn@2
    displayName: 'yarn ${{ parameters.arguments }} ${{ parameters.projectDirectory }}'

    inputs:
      ProjectDirectory: '${{ parameters.projectDirectory }}'
      Arguments: ${{ parameters.arguments }}
```